# Where this orange margin is coming from?

Tags: html, css, margin, move

I'm trying to create my portfolio website and I'm not sure where the 78.500 margin on the right side of the image is coming from?

I set my container of that image and the caption underneath in html as:

```css
.main__img--container {
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#main__img {
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  clip-path: circle();
}

.caption {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #87CEEB;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #4169E1 0%, #33cee2 100%);
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.caption2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #87CEEB;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #4169E1 0%, #33cee2 100%);
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<figure class="main__image--container">
  <img src="images/Profile Photo.jpg" class="profile" alt="pic" id="main__img">
  <figcaption class="caption">Daichi Furukawa</figcaption>
  <figcaption class="caption2">Cognitive Systems under Computer Science at UBC</figcaption>
</figure>
```

I played around the margin in `#main__img`, but it didn't change anything.

I would like to get rid of the 78.500 margin so I can put my image more on the right side of the page.

Even when I change the width from % to px, it still creates the margin on the right side of the page...

[image: The orange margin]

Answer (score 0):

This margin is generated when you applied width to your image

```
#main__img {
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    clip-path: circle();
}
```

Use some other property to achieve the results you're looking for.

Comment: What kind of property can I use to achieve the result? The scaling of the width and height perfectly changes my image size, but is there a way to just get rid of the margin?

Comment: @awakuruf You can use some properties from the flexbox. ```justify-content: center;```

Answer (score 0):

The code given in your question is far from complete to really get a reliable answer, but I see that your image has 80% width inside its parent element `.main__img--container`. So most likely that "margin" is the empty 20% which are left of the container's width. (Also the centered position of the caption in the screenshot you posted would fit to that)

Comment: So how would I exactly fix this problem? Does using % within the parent dig class would keep the margin on the right?

Comment: It leaves 20% of empty space. And again: You'd need to post the complete (or at least much more) code to get answers that don't need to be partly based on guessing.

Answer (score 0):

As above, width is set to 80%, leaving 20% of empty space. Try floating it to the right:

`float: right;`

That should push it all the way to the right and switch the margin to the left of the image instead.